# Rescatar un dato desde un texto con expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

quisiera consultar sobre una forma por medio de una expresión regular para extraer del texto siguiente el nombre que está marcado en negro

este es un ejemplo de lectura de un documento que viene por OCR:

> **JOSE ANTONIO VEGA SANCHEZ** | D. IDENTTFICACION I C.C. 3.131.656 I BANCO

La idea es generar una expresión regular que pueda sacar solo el nombre que está en negrita que en este caso es `JOSE ANTONIO VEGA SANCHEZ`, espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias por la cooperación en este caso.

Comment: el nombre siempre sera separado por | ?

Comment: No necesariamente pero tener una base con ese delimitador seria ideal porque despues se necesitaria solo cambiar el | por la palabra clave. @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav

Comment: La idea era usar el split usando el |  como pivote para obtener el nombre, cual es la nomenclatura que tiene ese archivo? ya que el |  no es común para cada registro cual seria?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav es de un .pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tus string limita los campos por medio un pipe, podes usar la siguiente expresión:

```
^(.*)\|
```

donde

- **^** indica el comienzo del string
- **(.*)** captura cualquier carácter imprimible en el grupo $1
- **\|** escapa el pipe para finalizar la captura del grupo.

Comment: Seria más o menos eso, pero sin el | solo el nombre completo pero ya es una gran ayuda.